# Is there a place where one can see the beginning of the universe?

Tags: big-bang-theory, night-sky

If the night sky Is dark because we’re seeing the world as it was a long time ago, when there wasn’t much to see, is there a place on the universe where we can see the universe at the  beginning of time? Where we can look at light from the moment of the Big Bang ?

Comment: *"we’re seeing the world as it was a long time ago, when there wasn’t much to see,"* That's not quite right. Most of the stars we can see with the naked eye are relative close, less than a few hundred lightyears away. With dark skies (and good eyes) we can see more distant parts of the Milky Way, and our near neighbour galaxies: the Magellanic Clouds, Andromeda, Triangulum, but we can't see individual stars in those regions.

Comment: There is [The Restaurant at the End of the Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Restaurant_at_the_End_of_the_Universe) but I don't think that that's necessarily what you're looking for.

Comment: The moment you think of is seen as cosmic background radiation and within the current understanding it is seen wherever you go.